# Why import default return "undefined" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm using file-loader to reference assets (images for example) but it return `undefined`:

**Project files**

(the `dist/*` files are generated by webpack)

```
dist/
  f74c4286ea273ec33454127cc4d1dee7.png
  main.js

img/
  img.jpg

src/
  index.ts

tsconf.json
webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.ts**

```
const path = import("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: { loader: "ts-loader" }
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: { loader: "file-loader" }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "include": ["./src/*.ts"]
}
```

**src/index.ts**

```
import A from "../img/img.png";
import * as B from "../img/img.png";

console.log('A', A);
console.log('B', B);
```

**result**

```
A undefined
B f74c4286ea273ec33454127cc4d1dee7.png
```

(I know that I should configure webpack to set the public folder but the point is not there)

**If I do the same minimal code in js, by removing ts-loader, tsconfig.json and renaming index.ts to index.js it work fine in the both cases... why ?**